# CodeIgniter Database Migration Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, database-migration

while I am migrating my database in codeigniter by url : hostname/project-name/api/migrate/
error shows as shown in the figure[image: Internal Server Error]

Please help me to fix

Comment: Whats in this url `hostname/project-name/api/migrate/`? What it suppose to do?

Comment: this will load migration files from the directory and will migrate tables defined in php files

Comment: See Apache `error_log` file. It should contain specific error.

Comment: Please post the controller and migration class.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code to .htaccess file . i think it should help

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /hafer

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddType text/x-component .htc.

AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```